# Brand new Windows 10 laptop: "wrong password"

Tags: windows-10, password-recovery

I just unboxed a laptop and went through the setup steps, including setting up a user "foobar" with password "1234". Finally the setup completed, the computer rebooted, and presented me with a password prompt for the user "foobar".

And then it says my password is wrong!
How in the world do I get away from this situation??

Windows even offers a "reset password" link right there. But that one requires a USB stick with a pw-reset file that I should have created earlier - except the setup didn't even offer me this option.

I'm fine with resetting the machine - but according to the manual(!) that is a function I can access *inside Windows*. Very funny, Microsoft... I don't have a setup disk of course, there was none supplied.

Comment: According to what manual, exactly? It may simply be incorrect. If it were that easy to reset your password, passwords would be entirely worthless.

Comment: I would boot into the bios and do a factory restore.

Comment: You might be stuck if it's attached to an MS account, but, [according to the internet](https://www.lifewire.com/offline-nt-password-and-registry-editor-review-2626147), [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) still works with Windows 10 local accounts (but I can't personally verify that). It certainly works through Win7 and the official website lists Win8.1 and Server 2012 as compatible OSes. If your do decide to give it a try, I've found the best course is to simply blank the password, rather  than trying to set a new one.

Comment: @Moab there is no such setting in the BIOS (or technically, it's not a BIOS but rather an UEFI).

Comment: UEFI-Bios, same thing, hardware bootstrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself:

1. The logon screen has a power button in the bottom right corner.
2. Hold down the SHIFT key,
3. Click or touch that button,
4. Select "Restart".

The system launches into a recovery mode where I can choose several different kinds of software reset.

Among them is the option of a complete factory reset. That process takes several hours. All data is lost, and the result is a brand-new start.